# JavaScript - sending data from form on one page to show on another page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form on one page (form.html) with inputs for user (species, temperature(low)). I want to be able to input data, click the submit button and show the values on another webpage (customanimal.html) I'll be redirected to. Here is the form.html code:

```
<form id="form" method="GET" action="customanimal.html">
                            Species: <input type="text" name="species" id="species">
                            Temperature(low): <input type="text" name="templow" id="templow">
                            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()">
                            </form>
                            <script>
                            function submitForm(){
                                if(typeof(localStorage) != "undefined"){
                                    localStorage.name = document.getElementById("species").value;
                                }
                                document.getElementById("form").submit();
                            }
                            </script>
```

And here is the customanimal.html form:

```
<body onload="setData()">
    <p id="show">
    Name: <!-- want to display the name here -->
    </p>
    <script>
    function setData(){
        if(typeof(localStorage) != "undefined"){
            document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = localStorage.name;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

It works as it should, but only for one input. So if I input both "species" and "temperature(low), only the species will show up on the redirect.

How can I make it so that every input shows up?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you keep overwriting `localStorage.name`, just use multiple properties: `localStorage.species` for instance. However in the long run you'll want to use a proper backend that actually processes the form being sent and saves the data in a database/session.

Comment: @ChrisG turned out it needed a special <p id="xy"></p> and then corresponding document.getElementById("xy") to show up correctly. Thank you tho, your comment lead me to the right solution!